# Get Value from Column that has a particular value in the row above

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a datatable that has three columns: 
Date,
Timestamp, 
Part Number (456)
Exchange Time (Time that it took to change dies from Part Number 123 to start producing Part Number 456 in minutes)

A die Exchange Process is not symmetric, meaning changing from 123 to 456 is very different compared to changing from 456 to 123

The Timestamp allows me to order the rows in the correct order of time. The Query includes two  parameters to select the part Number the Machine started with and the one it produced afterwards, with the goal of displaying the Exchange time in a line chart.

What I am struggling with is implementing the logic of the process: If I select the two part numbers as parameters ( Part Number from , Part Number to) I need to select the time from the row of "Part Number to" that had "Part Number from" in the Row Above (lower Timestamp).

Comment: Please provide sample data and the corresponding desired result.  If you attempted any queries post them as well.

Comment: I guess you will end up to use a cursor.

Comment: The table design is terrible.  If you can change it, that's what you should do

Comment: I agree the table design is bad, however i can not change it...